# How to adjust seek bar automatically from user input?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am following some code i found online to build my first app. The app contains a textfield where a user can enter their guess as a number(from 1-100). If the number matches the random number generated by the computer, then they will get a reward. I am using a seek bar that the user can use. But my question how can i synchronize the user input and the seek bar. I mean suppose, I enter 45 in the "text box" and it will automatically move the seek bar from its current position to 45. Thank you so much for your help. Here is the part of my code.

```
    private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = 
      new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
   {

      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
         boolean fromUser) 
      {
         // sets currentCustomPercent to position of the SeekBar's thumb
         currentCustomPercent = seekBar.getProgress();


         updateCustom(); 
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
      {
      } // end method onStartTrackingTouch

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
      {
      }    }; 
private void updateCustom() 
   {

      customTipTextView.setText(currentCustomPercent + "");


boolean guessIsCorrect=(winningNumber==currentCustomPercent);
double customTipAmount =(guessIsCorrect?currentBillTotal:0);

      double customTotalAmount = currentBillTotal - customTipAmount;


      tipCustomEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", customTipAmount));
      totalCustomEditText.setText(
         String.format("%.02f", customTotalAmount));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
seekBar.setProgress(int progress)
```

to set the progress to the seekbar. You should mind in the listener, in the onProgressChanged method, the fromUser param.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int)

Comment: Hi, I have added that extra line of code in onProgressChanged method, but its not working yet.The seek bar doesn't update from user guess

Comment: you should not add it in the onProgressChanged method! actually the onProgressChanged will be called after you call setProgress, that's why you have the fromUser flag, to know if it was programmatically set or by the user.